# Why the grease pencil object partly disappeared while rotating the viewport angle?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

Why the grease pencil object partly disappeared while rotating the viewport angle?
The green ground is filled with grease pencil while the trees are sketched with grease pencil.
P.S.The value of [Clip end: 10000] is set in both View and camera.

Comment: in the layers tab, under Strokes, did you try changing depth order to 3d location?

Comment: The grease pencil trees object is partly disappeared after changing to 3D location. https://imgur.com/goGN8rG